# getchar() working in C

Tags: c

`getchar()` inside `while` loop takes input after printing whole string. Can anyone explain how `getchar()` and `putchar()` works?

I am including following code snippet and output. Also unable to understand behavior of this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int c ;
    c = getchar();
    while(c!=EOF){
        putchar(c);
        printf("%d\n",EOF);
        printf("before getchar in while loop");
        c=getchar();
        printf("after getchar in while loop");
        printf("jas\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV58O.png)

Comment: I guess it's the two `-1` printed on the output baffled you. So simply whenever you press ENTER or space then that character will be consumed by `getchar()` and that is outputted by `putchar`. Your are printing `EOF` which nothing but `-1` and taht's what you see. 
You can add this line to filter out alphabetic charcaters.  `if( !isspace(c) ) putchar(c);`

Comment: If you are using Windows, after entering the string, press Enter and then control-Z (that is, hold the CTRL key down while pressing Z) and then Enter again.  If you are using anything other than Windows, instead, after entering the string, press Enter and then control-D; a second Enter is not required.  Either way, that should cause `getchar` to return EOF.

Comment: Post output here.

Comment: Well whatever you commented - that is explained in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar` is eventually being handled through to the console input management routines.  These routines, in a default config (no `ioctl` or equivalent calls), will read and echo the entire line before returning the string to the program for processing.  Once returned, getchar will be prepared to process the entire line before it goes back to the console input routines.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

The int getchar(void) function reads the next available character from the screen and returns it as an integer. This function reads only single character at a time. You can use this method in the loop in case you want to read more than one character from the screen.

The int putchar(int c) function puts the passed character on the screen and returns the same character. This function puts only single character at a time. You can use this method in the loop in case you want to display more than one character on the screen. Check the following example −

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( ) {

   int c;

   printf( "Enter a value :");
   c = getchar( );

   printf( "\nYou entered: ");
   putchar( c );

   return 0;
}
```

When the above code is compiled and executed, it waits for you to input some text. When you enter a text and press enter, then the program proceeds and reads only a single character and displays it as follows −

```
$./a.out
Enter a value : this is test
You entered: t
```

reference : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_input_output.htm

Comment: Hi Harshit I think you didn't got point ,  i am saying that getchar always expect some input from user as the control pause to get input from user at line 6(before while statement) but control doesn't pause at getchar() inside while loop to get input from user.How this flow is working ??
Thanks for your quick response. :)

Comment: control does pause to get input from user . Its working fine on my side.