# Refresh screen every 1 second with ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I want to refresh the screen every one second. I'm implementing a chat with ncurses.

So far, I have the following function:

```
void print_chat(char *chat) {
    mvprintw(1, 1, "RPC Chat");
    
    move(2, 1);
    for (int i=0; i<CHAT_WIDTH; i++) {
        addch('_');
    }

    move(CHAT_HEIGHT + 3, 1);
    for (int i=0; i<CHAT_WIDTH; i++) {
        addch('_');
    }
    
    mvprintw(CHAT_HEIGHT + 5, 1, "Enter message: ");
}
```

Which prints the following screen:

[image]

In the main function I'd like to have a loop that refreshes the screen every 1 second, obtaining possible new messages from a server, and refreshes the screen in that interval so if any, new messages could be displayed. I also want to read users input while the refreshing goes on at the same time. Do I need threads?

My attempt so far in the main function:

```
while (1) {
    print_chat(chat);
    refresh();
    sleep(1);

    chat = read_chat_from_server();
    /*char l = getch(); --> This would block the loop, waiting for input... 
}
```

Do I need threads to achieve this? If so, would the thread be able to reprint the screen? Any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Obligatory comment: ❶ one second is a _long_ time ❷ Don’t spam `wrefresh()` — It is nicely optimized but it is still better to design your code to only update when necessary: wait on input using `poll()` (or `epoll()`), read and process that input, then output any desired changes and `wrefresh()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getch()` is waiting for the user to press return.

You want to have a look at [`raw()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/raw) and call it once before getting any input. By calling this function you can get characters from the user without him pressing return, pausing your program. Basically the console reads user input, prints each character as its being written, and **when the user sends `'\n'`**, it returns that input to your program (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47950296/11715554)).

You might want to look at [`noecho()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/noecho) too. Similar to `raw()`, lets you scan for user input (using `getch()`) without printing the characters on the screen. This is usually useful for letting your program handle how the characters are displayed.

Finally, it may be a good idea to call `refresh()` when something gets updated (e.g. check each second if you got a message, you sent one, etc.) and then call `refresh()`. If you still want to run it every second, maybe try [`nodelay(stdscr, 1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/nodelay), where `stdscr` is your default window:

> The nodelay option causes getch to be a non-blocking call. If no input is ready, getch returns ERR. If disabled (bf is FALSE), getch waits until a key is pressed.

Comment: So does this mean I don't need any `getch()`? I have tried the `raw()` calling before the loop and without any `getch()`, but the programs seems to remain locked, none of the users input is echoed when the keys are typed. Also, where would I get the user inputs from?

Comment: By calling `raw()` once, the user does not need to press return for you to receive the characters. The method for receiving them is the same, using `getch()`, but it will receive them immediately. You don't need threads, by the way.

Comment: So, just to clarify, I would still need a `getch()` call inside the loop which will be reading character by character any input, without blocking the loop, so it could keep iterating and refreshing the screen each second?

Comment: Exactly. You need `getch()` to read the input. `raw()` only makes it so the user doesn't have to press return before you get the char.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `timeout()` function when you first initialize your program.

`timeout(0)` should cause `getch()` to not wait for user input.

Comment: See also [`nodelay()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/nodelay).